# iMacros - How to Scrape Results from Bing Related searches as TXT for each value?

Tags: firefox-addon, imacros

[image]

I need to scrape or grab Related searches when searching with any keyword.

However, in a red box I mark. iMacros can be scrape with EXTRACT:HTM.

So, I must manually edit to extract them as TXT line by line for each time.

Is there any solution to separate the result to TXT for each before saving to CSV?

This is my code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:b_rich EXTRACT=HTM
```

Thanks

Comment: Those Related Searches seem to be always 8 Links => Simply hard-code (8x times) extracting those 8 Links (as '=TXT'), eventually using 'R-Pos' on the "Related searches" 'H2' Element as 'Anchor'...

Comment: Hum, wanted to comment that I was not "really impressed" by the Follow-up, 3 days later, but I see a '+1' on my previous Comment, maybe from you @OP...?  => Post your Script as "Answer" to your own Qt if you understood my "Advice" and I can still "guide" you if needed...  [You would need to mention your FCI for me to post a Script as "Answer", I don't post Scripts when FCI is not mentioned...]